# Problem with texture

Tags: texturing, uv

Good daytime. Problem with applying texture, how can it be fixed? Thanks! [image]

Comment: hello, you need to check your uv map in the UV Editor

Comment: Hello, I have checked nothing special.

Comment: maybe select these faces in Edit mode and unwrap again?

Comment: "Nothing special", but definitely there is something wrong since the side top parts are infinitely stretched - which should not be with a correctly unwrapped mesh. Would you mind sharing a screenshot of the map in the UV Editor?

Answer (score 0):

So, basically the problem was in "correct face attributes". It should be turned on to fix that kind of bugs. Thanks!